# Wordpress Amp Domain

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I use amp for wp and amp for wp subdomain plugin. And so far everything is smooth. My links are directed to cdn ampproject through a subdomain. But what I want to do is to publish my amp page through a custom domain and sometimes change this domain. First of all, how can I do this through a completely custom domain? Then, when I change my domain, how can I send mobile serp visitors to this new link without any problems? And while this is happening, the cdn ampproject url must adapt to this.
Thanks.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution to this, I'm not sure what I should do on both the WP side and the DNS side.